# Function to match columns and values to rows - intersection of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, match, typeerror

Lets say I have the following DataFrame:

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame([[5,2,3,11],[5,3,3,8],[9,4,11,12],[5,14,15,16]],columns=["a","b","c","d"])
>>>df
   a   b   c   d
0  5   2   3  11
1  5   3   3   8
2  9   4  11  12
3  5  14  15  16
```

If I wanted to match all the rows which had the column values: 'a' equal to 5, 'b' < 10 and 'c' greater than or equal to 3, I could just do the following:

```
df[(df['a'] == 5) & (df['b'] < 10) & (df['c'] >= 3)]
```

and that would give me the result I was after:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  5  2  3  11
1  5  3  3   8
```

Entering that code to match the rows was laborious so I decided to make a function called `row_matcher` which would take 2 arguments: a Pandas DataFrame and a list of lists of length 3 - column of choice, operator and value.

```
def get_operator_fn(op):
    import operator
    return {
        '<' : operator.lt,
        '<=' : operator.le,
        '==' : operator.eq,
        '!=' : operator.ne,
        '>=' : operator.ge,
        '>' : operator.gt,
        '&' : operator.and_
        }[op]

def row_matcher(df,parameters):
    import pandas as pd
    """Parameter should be [column,operation,value]
    Example: ['trial',"==",1]
    """
    operations = [df[get_operator_fn(operation)(df[column],value)] for column,operation,value in parameters]
    return reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,how='inner'), operations)

>>>row_matcher(df,[["a","==",5],["b","<",10],["c",">=",3]])
```

Unfortunately with this code it throws up an error for the `return reduce(...)` line: 
`TypeError: Could not compare <type 'str'> type with Series`

I tried replacing the `return reduce(...)` line with:
`df[reduce(operator.and_,operations)]`

This still results in an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'`

I would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I think this would be a lot simpler using the [query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method.  Using this, your initial example can be written as:

```
df.query('a==5 & b<10 & c>=3')
```

Honestly, if you use the query() method, I don't think you'd gain much from your function, unless you're reading in lots of conditions from an external file.  If still want to write the `row_matcher` function, just use string joins to combine your list of lists as a single string, obeying the query() syntax.  Once you have a single string, pass it along to the query() method.

You may need to install the `numexpr` module to use the query() method.  You can get around this by supplying the keyword argument `engine='python'` to query() method.  This may be less efficient than using the `numexpr` module, so it might be worthwhile to install the module if performance becomes an issue.

Comment: i had to install and import the numexpr module to get it to work.

Comment: @floydn: Me too.  I didn't know if it was just me that was missing it, or if it is something that may be commonly be missing.  I'll edit my answer to address a keyword argument that can be supplied to avoid using numexpr.